# Enum == vs switch (one item)

Tags: java, performance, enums, conventions

Note: I am working on something to test this, I just thought it would be a good idea to see of someone else has the answer before I get to it.

Lets say that one needs to implement the following interface method (where `Operation` in an `enum`)

```
public boolean supportsOperation(Operation op)
```

It is obvious that if the class supports more than one operation, you would use a switch, and if the class doesn't support operations at all, you return false. My question is this:

If the class only supports one type of `Operation`, would it be better and/or faster to implement the method like `return op == Operation.SomeOperation` or to use something like:

```
switch (op){
    case SomeOperation:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

I do note that when given `null` the first one returns false and the second throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I prefer first method. You can always use `if` statements instead of `switch` (which I also prefer).

Comment: **Beware premature optimization!** - Never choose a certain syntax or pattern  for performance considerations unless you have **proven by measurement** tat you actually *have* a performance issue **and** the chosen variant *really solve that*.  Otherwise stay with the version that best expresses your intent.

Comment: What is the most readable? The first one is clearly more. And if you had to support several operations, a switch would still be far less readable than `return SUPPORTED_OPERATIONS.contains(op);`, where SUPPORTED_OPERATIONS would be a constant initialized with `Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Operation.OP1, Operation.OP1, Operation.OP1))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Better** is opinion, however *faster* is answerable: they would be **exactly** the same. The compiler is quite capable of making such trivial optimizations (and the JIT gets a second pass to make even more optimizations). You should spend your time on more productive things (like implementing your operations).

Also, if you still want to pursue this topic further (good), I recommend you at least watch [What has my compiler done for me lately](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) and play with [gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/).

Comment: And that is why I asked while trying to figure it out. Thank-you!